Debian - apt-get upgrade throwing error
When running sudo apt-get upgrade I get the following error:
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10

The same thing occurs when using the Discover application to update packages. Most applications are able to be updated, but system software isn't. This is particularly problematic as security updates are unable to be installed / downloaded.
What I'm running:
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
Host: Intel Z690
Kernel: 6.1.0-26-amd64
Packages: 2520 (dpkg), 35 (flatpak), 8 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.2.15
DE: Plasma 5.27.5
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i3-12100F (8) @ 5.500GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate


I’m guessing that apt-listchanges was installed in the past, but no longer is, and its configuration files are still present. To fix this, purge the package without using apt:
sudo dpkg --purge apt-listchanges

In particular, this should remove /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges which is the culprit in this instance.
If that doesn’t work, delete the configuration file:
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges


dpkg is unable to remove it as it isn't installed. I've checked the directory you mentioned too, and i don't have that file.

Apologies, I mixed up apt-listbugs and apt-listchanges. See the updated answer.

Sorry, now it just says Removing apt-listchanges (3.24) ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found dpkg: error processing package apt-listchanges (--purge):  installed apt-listchanges package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127 Deferring configuration of apt-listchanges until /usr/bin/python3 and python's debconf module are available /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-listchanges.postinst: 212: py3compile: not found . I assume i'm missing some python package or something.

Have you replaced Python by any chance?

I don't really know to be honest. When running type python python2 python3 none of the packages are found, but if I try to install python3, I get python3 is already the newest version (3.11.2-1+b1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed.. I then get the same error message mentioned in my initial question when I type y to continue.

What does python3 --version say?

command not found

OK, so Python is broken on your system. If you delete the configuration file (see the updated answer) you should at least be able to run sudo apt upgrade a little better (it will still fail on any package requiring Python). To fix Python, run sudo apt reinstall python3-minimal.
